# Magento 2: Get orders filtering customer email

Tags: magento2, orders, collection, order-email

Is there any way to get the orders by filtering by the client's email?

I'm trying

```
 $ordersCollection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create();
 $ordersCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
 $ordersCollection->addFieldToFilter('customer_email',$customerEmail);
 $ordersCollection->setPageSize($pagesize);
 $ordersCollection->setCurPage($page);
```

but not work the filter.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can Following this way..

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
    ) 
    {
        $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    }

public function getOrderCollection()
{
    $orderCollecion = $this->orderCollectionFactory
        ->create()
        ->addFieldToSelect('*');

    $orderCollecion->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email', 'xyz@gmail.com');

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($orderCollecion->getData());
    exit; 
    return $orderCollecion;
}
```

Comment: Ok. That works! thnk!